# 'duration' in second to minute 00:00

Tags: wordpress

I have this code in my index.php for my video blog, the duration is in second for exemple 1238
I would to convert this value 'duration' in 20:38 an show in my video box

```
<div class="post-duration"><?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true) ) ; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true) ; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

```
function totime ($seconds)
{        
    return floor($seconds / 60) . ':' . ($seconds % 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really show what you have tried first, not just ask for an answer, however, since you are new to StackOverflow. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt, and show you the solution.

```
$seconds = 1238;
$minutes = (int)( $seconds / 60);

$seconds -= $minutes * 60;

echo $minutes.":".$seconds;
```

Try to ask "What is wrong with my solution?", NOT, "What is the solution?"